# Why can't nightwatch find my dom?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch for integration test and it failed to find one of  my dom element. Below is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; height: 24px;">
        <div class="GPNWDJGEV" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
          </div>
        <div id="gwt-debug-MenuItem" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Below is nightwatch code.

```
module.exports = {
  'Connection Test' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('file:///tmp/test.html')
      .waitForElementVisible("#gwt-debug-MenuItem", 5000)
      .pause(1000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

I got below error when running this test case:

```
✖ Timed out while waiting for element <#gwt-debug-MenuItem> to be visible for 5000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not visible"
```

I am able to find other dom element but failed to find this one `#gwt-debug-MenuItem`. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Is there a `<iframe>` tag in the html?

Comment: It doesn't have iframe.  I pasted all my html file in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the element is not really visible. Try waiting for its presence instead with `waitForElementPresent`

```
module.exports = {
  'Connection Test' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('file:///tmp/test.html')
      .waitForElementPresent("#gwt-debug-MenuItem", 5000)
      .pause(1000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank youuuu! Searched a bunch for this. `waitForElementVisible` should become `waitForElementPresent`

Comment: Work for me too, but I am a little bit confused since the code sample on official [nightwatch.js site](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-nightwatch) uses `waitForElementVisible`. Is it not supposed to work with ?